# SYSTEMConfigPerformance not executing in PIC32

Tags: pic, c, frequency

I have `PIC32MX795F512L` MCU and I am working on its `UART` communication. I have made the program and its working fine. I was curious about the frequency my PIC is running so I searched a little bit and found this online [document](http://microchip.wikidot.com/32bit:mx-systemconfigperformance-plib) which says that :

> **SYSTEMConfigPerformance()** is a very helpful library function used to easily optimize the performance of the PIC32. You provide the system (instruction) clock frequency and this function will do the rest. It will perform the following tasks for you:

1. Enable instruction and data caching
2. Enable instruction prefetch
3. Configure the Flash and SRAM for minimum wait states
4. Maximize the peripheral bus clock frequency

So when I included the `SYSTEMConfigPerformance(FCY)` in my code, my UART communication stops and I was receiving some random chars. When I excluded the `SYSTEMConfigPerformance(FCY)` it wwas working fine. I don't know the reason behind this strange behavior. I am using `8MHZ` crystal with PLL and finally running my PIC at `72MHZ` frequency. Following is the code I am using:

```
#define FCY 72000000UL
#define FPB (FCY/2)
#define BAUDRATE    9600
#pragma config POSCMOD=HS,FNOSC=PRIPLL 
#pragma config FPLLIDIV=DIV_2, FPLLMUL=MUL_18, FPLLODIV=DIV_1
#pragma config FPBDIV=DIV_2, FWDTEN=OFF, CP=OFF, BWP=OFF

int main()
{
  SYSTEMConfigPerformance(FCY); //<-- Problem is at this line.
  OpenUART1( UART_EN | UART_NO_PAR_8BIT | UART_1STOPBIT, UART_RX_ENABLE | UART_TX_ENABLE, (FPB/16/BAUDRATE)-1 );
  while(1)
  {
     putsUART1("Hello\n");
  }
}

void DelayMs( unsigned t)
{
T1CON = 0x8000;
while (t--)
{
    TMR1 = 0;
    while (TMR1 < FPB/1000);
}
}
```

Comment: On a different question, did the UART finally work at 115200 baud? What did you change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is late but when you are including `SYSTEMConfigPerformance(FCY);` you will also have to change `OpenUART1()`. Try following :

```
int x;
x = SYSTEMConfigPerformance(FCY);
OpenUART1( UART_EN | UART_NO_PAR_8BIT | UART_1STOPBIT, UART_RX_ENABLE | UART_TX_ENABLE, (x/16/BAUDRATE)-1 );
```

Replace `FPB` with `x`. It should work.!

Comment: yes its working. But my DelayMs function is not working, delay 1sec is like 500ms.??

Answer (score 1):

SYSTEMConfigPerformance() also sets the FPB (peripheral bus frequency) divider to the highest performance value, in this case the same as your system clock, so it is running at 72 MHz instead of your expected 36 MHz, thus your baud rate assumptions are incorrect.

You can instead call the following function, and leave out the PB bus configuration flag:

```
SYSTEMConfig(FCY, SYS_CFG_WAIT_STATES | SYS_CFG_PCACHE);
```

The other option is to just run the peripheral bus at the 72 MHz instead, and just change your #define value:

```
#define FPB (FCY)
```

Comment: I didn't get you. How can FPB be same as system clock when I am setting it to `FCY/2`& `FPBDIV=DIV_2` in fuse settings.

Comment: @user007  The value gets set to divide by 2 initially in the hidden startup code from your pragma, but then the SYSTEMConfigPerformance() function then modifies it during run time.  It is just another register value in memory like anything else.

Comment: @user007 The term "Fuse" is not very accurate for these processors.  They are simply register values that can be changed just like any other code (mostly).  No weird high voltages or anything are required to adjust them. (some special registers require an unlock code, but that is the exception)

Comment: In that case, FCY and FPB will become same which I think will effect other things like the Delay function I have made to provide delay. Also then there will be no use of including `FPBDIV=DIV_2`

Comment: @user007 Only if you keep the current function.  You can replace it with the function I suggested, and it won't changed your PB clock and you things will all operate the same.

Comment: But in all the examples of Microchip. they include this FPB and `FPBDIV=DIV_2` along with `SYSTEMConfigPerformance()`

Comment: I guess that is a copy paste of stuff that worked, and then call a single function to configure the PIC32 at highest performance settings. The  SYSTEMConfig function can individually tune parts of the controller 'correctly'.